# How can I get a minecraft server icon using python?

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm using mcstatus to query information from my friend's minecraft server but I'm having trouble getting the icon. I found [this](https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus/issues/11) code but `server.favicon` doesn't seem to exist. I can't find any documentation on this either. My code:

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer

server = MinecraftServer(HOST, PORT)
print(server.favicon)
```

Error:

```
print(server.favicon)
AttributeError: 'MinecraftServer' object has no attribute 'favicon'
```

Should I be using a different library for this? Or am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Why do you think there is something like `server.favicon`?

Comment: If you scroll down [here](https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus/issues/11) it shows an example of how its used. I thought it would still be the same, I guess not

Comment: But your code is different.

Comment: .ping_server() doesn't seem to exist, so I had to improvise. Or at least I tried to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: added .status():

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer


server = MinecraftServer(HOST, PORT).status()
status = server
if status.favicon:
  print(status.favicon)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the code example provided uses the ping_server method. Try the following:

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer

server = MinecraftServer(HOST, PORT)
status = server.ping_server()
if status.favicon:
  print(status.favicon)
```

Comment: .ping_server() method doesn't exist

Comment: Tried that too, it gives an error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'favicon'`